# Delta Lake Compacting Multiple files to single file

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I am currently exploring delta lake which is open sourced by databricks. I am reading kafka data and writing as stream using delta lake format. Delta lake creates many files during streaming write from kafka which i feel hearts hdfs file system.

I have tried following to compact multiple files to single file.

```
val spark =  SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("spark session example")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.read.parquet("deltalakefile/data/")

  df.repartition(1).write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("deltalakefile/data/")
  df.show()

  spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled","false")

  DeltaTable.forPath("deltalakefile/data/").vacuum(1)
```

But when i checked output it is creating new file and not removing any existing files.

Is there is way to achieve this. Also what is relation of retention period here? How should we configure it in HDFS while using? What should be my configuration for retention when i want to build raw/bronze layer with delta lake format and i want to preserve my all data for long period (years on premises/infinite time on cloud)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, Delta doesn't immediately remove files to prevent active consumers from being impacted. It also provides the versioning (aka time-travel) so you can see history if necessary. To remove previous versions or uncommitted files you need to run [vacuum](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#delta-vacuum).

```
import io.delta.tables._

val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, pathToTable)

deltaTable.vacuum() // use default retention period
```

In terms of your question on how to manage retention and compaction for bronze/silver/gold model, you should treat your landing table (aka bronze) as an append-only log. That means you don't need to perform compaction or any rewrites after the fact. The bronze table should be a record of the data you ingested from your upstream data source (e.g. Kafka) with minimal processing applied.

The bronze table is typically used as an incremental stream source to populate downstream datasets. Given that reading from Delta is done from the transaction log, small files is not such an issue compared to using the standard file readers that perform slow file listings.

However, there are still some some options to optimize the files as you write them to the bronze table: 1) compact your Kafka messages as you write out to Delta by first repartitioning to reduce the number of files, 2) increase your trigger interval so the ingest runs less frequently and is writing more messages to larger files.

Comment: Hi Silvio thanks for help. Ok so if i have file lets say one day old then only my above command will work is it right. Also please provide me idea of retention period if i use vaccum(1) will it delete all old files which are committed.?

Comment: If you run a `vacuum(1)` you're saying remove everything older than 1 hour. The default retention period is 7 days.

Comment: Can i override that and make it to delete 1 hour old files.

Comment: Yes, you can specify 0 but please read the warning in the docs https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#delta-vacuum

Comment: Yes gone through it. Then what might be other ways to compact files.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the issue is. You compact the files which creates a new snapshot. You then can vacuum using the default 7 day retention or you can override it and vacuum all prior versions. This isn't a problem with compaction, right? The point is you do not want to immediately remove the current table snapshot since you might have active consumers.

Comment: You are right. What i am trying to solve is when we are using it as streaming sink and when source is kafka. I am getting too many files. Now lets say if i want to compact old hourly portioned data from many files to single file then what are the options. Yes vaccum is there but documentation says that you will lose time travel which scares me to take that route. So looking for other ways to do it.

Comment: I updated the original response to clarify on file sizes for streaming ingest

Comment: Thanks Silvio your updated response mostly answers my questions. Just one last question on same line is writing to many small files even including transaction logs in case of delta hurts HDFS namenode and its file management process.

Comment: Again, if you truly have too many small files you should repartition before writing and increase your trigger interval. That should help reduce the number of files being written in each batch.

Comment: Does this approach apply to non-delta lake implementations? I am simply writing data from some SQL sources to a partitioned year/month/day dataset. Since I need to download data every 15 minutes, I end up with a lot of small files inside the day partition and I am looking for best practices. Should I write a second dataset which repartitions it into a single file per day and leave the "bronze" dataset as is?

Comment: If you're using Spark and storing data to cloud storage just use Delta and follow the suggestions above. For your reporting or analytical tables (e.g. "gold") you can periodically compact each new partition, Delta will give you the ability to do it in-place safely with ACID guarantees.

Comment: I am trying to run a compaction on a delta table (streaming sink) where the spark job is performing MERGE on this table for every 5 minutes. At the time of compaction is being executed on the table, if there are updates happening on the same table, how does the it work? Should we wait until the compaction is executed successfully before resuming the updates or spark can manage it? Also, are there any guidelines available to consider the repartition number? I mean, I have 1000 small files and is it best to repartition to 10 or to even 5?